# using document.getElementId in Switch Statement in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, jsx, dom-manipulation

I want a certain graph displayed, depending upon the inner text in "#pairName", Can't seem to figure out why this wouldn't work. My full code can be found at: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-lake-6h051?file=/src/App.js, for better a understanding of the code.

```
  displayGraph = () => { 
      switch(document.getElementById('pairName').innerText){
        case 'USD/EUR':
            return <Graph selectedBase = {this.state.selectedBase} defaultBase={"EUR"} today ={this.state.EURfirstDateValues} lastWeek = {this.state.EURfifthDateValues}/>;
        case 'USD/CAD':
            return <Graph selectedBase = {this.state.selectedBase} defaultBase={"CAD"} today = {this.state.CADfirstDateValues} lastWeek = {this.state.CADfifthDateValues}/>;
        case 'USD/NZD':
            return <Graph selectedBase = {this.state.selectedBase} defaultBase={"NZD"} today = {this.state.NZDfirstDateValues} lastWeek = {this.state.NZDfifthDateValues}/>;
        case 'USD/AUD':
            return <Graph selectedBase = {this.state.selectedBase} defaultBase={"AUD"} today = {this.state.AUDfirstDateValues} lastWeek = {this.state.AUDfifthDateValues}/>;
        case 'USD/JPY':
            return <Graph selectedBase = {this.state.selectedBase} defaultBase={"JPY"} today = {this.state.JPYfirstDateValues} lastWeek = {this.state.JPYfifthDateValues}/>;

        }
}
```

```
<h2 id="pairName">USD/EUR</h2>
          {/* GOAL: show graphs when correct pairs are selected */}
          {this.displayGraph}
```

Comment: You should have a `default` case. Also, what exactly are you getting? I would add `console.log(`document.getElementById('pairName').innerText)` just prior to the `switch` to be sure you are accessing the correct data. Also, use `textContent` instead of `.innerText`.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing direct DOM manipulation in React. Store the value in state. Also `displayGraph` is a **function**, so it needs to be called: `{this.displayGraph()}`